# Height of an object given two projections

Tags: trigonometry

So have to measure the height of an object **$c$** given two known projections ($a$ and $b$). The angle $\phi$ between the two projections is known (it is 85.5°)

What is the length of $c$? (in terms of $\phi$, $a$ and $b$)

Before I was using the Pythagorean theorem, since the angle was thought to be 90°. Upon inspection it is not exactly 90° and thus the height of c is being underestimated.

My gut feeling is I need to use the Law of Cosines, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Notes:

- The object $c$ can be rotated like in the picture. The angle of rotation is unknown.
- $\alpha$ and $\beta$ angles are not given, but their sum equals $\phi$

[image: i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of an object is equal to its length multiplied by the cosine of the angle between the projection and the object. Note that from the diagram, $90 - \alpha$ is the cosine angle for projection $a$. So we have,
\begin{align}
 a &= c \cos \left(90 - \alpha\right) = c \sin \alpha &&\rightarrow \sin \alpha = \frac{a}{c} \\
 b &= c \sin \beta &&\rightarrow \sin \beta = \frac{b}{c}
\end{align}

Now we are also given the sum of these angles, $\phi$. So we can write one angle in terms of the other; i.e. $\alpha = \phi - \beta$. Applying the sine formula and expanding,
\begin{align}
 \sin \alpha &= \sin (\phi - \beta) = \sin \phi \cos \beta - \cos \phi \sin \beta \\
   \frac{a}{c} &= \sin \phi \frac{\sqrt{c^2 - b^2}}{c} - \cos \phi \frac{b}{c} 
\end{align}

For real problems, and if either $a$ or $b$ are non-zero, then $c$ will also be non-zero. So we can multiple throughout by $c$, and rearrange the rest to get,
\begin{gather}
   c = \sqrt{\left(\frac{a + b \cos \phi}{\sin \phi}\right)^2 + b^2} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos \phi}}{\sin \phi}
\end{gather}

And we can see that if $\phi = 90$, then the above reduces to the Pythagorean formula, as you were initially thinking.

Comment: Accepting this answer becaus it was the first, and the most elegant in my opinion, since it uses the more simple logic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the blue cyclic quadrilateral below around the required length $c$, with angles (clockwise from the top) $180^\circ - \phi$, $90^\circ$, $\phi$, and $90^\circ$:

[image: Diagram with additional annotation]

The required $c$ is the length of one diagonal. The length of the other diagonal can be found using the cosine law:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{The other diagonal} &= \sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(180^\circ-\phi)}\\
&= \sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\phi}
\end{align*}$$

$c$ is also the diameter of the circumcircle of the cyclic quad., which can be found by the sine law:

$$\begin{align*}
c = 2R &= \frac{\text{The other diagonal}}{\sin(180^\circ-\phi)}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\phi}}{\sin\phi}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

If we move the line segments $a$ and $b$ towards $c,$ we get something like the following
[image]

Due to the right angles at $A$ and $B$ and because of [Thales's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), we know that $c$ is the diameter of the circle that goes through $A$, $B$ and $P.$

The length of $d$ can be calculated by means of the law of cosines:
$$
d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\pi-\phi)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\phi}
$$
and the diameter of the circumcircle of the triangle $ABP$ can be computed as the length of any side of the triangle divided by the sine of the opposite angle, see [circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle). Therefore
$$
c = \frac {d}{\sin(\pi-\phi)}=\frac {d}{\sin\phi}
=\frac {\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\phi}}{\sin\phi}
$$